How do I highlight green where it says 'gain' and red where it says 'loss' using styles?
I am trying to create a table for technical indicators and am highlighting signal ages alongside if the signal is making a gain or a loss.
I have column bull which has values 'gain' or 'loss'.
How do I use styles to highlight gain values green and loss values red using Jupyter notebooks on VS Code?
This is what I tried but it is not displaying a table
def cts(x):
    c1 = 'color: red'
    c2 = 'color: green'
    c3 = 'color: white'
    if 'Gain' in x['Bull - Long Position']:
        return c3,c1,c1
    elif 'Loss' in x['Bull - Long Position']:
        return c3,c2,c2
    else:
        return c3,c3,c3

df = df.reset_index(drop=True).style.apply(cts, subset=['Strategy', 'Age', 'Long short indicator'], axis=1)


maybe you have to use print(df) or something similar to see table. In Jupyter it may need to add line with only df  to see value in df

Do something like this
import pandas as pd

data = {
    'Strategy': ['Strategy1', 'Strategy2', 'Strategy3', 'Strategy4'],
    'Age': [5, 10, 15, 20],
    'Long short indicator': ['Indicator1', 'Indicator2', 'Indicator3', 'Indicator4'],
    'Bull - Long Position': ['gain', 'loss', 'gain', 'loss']
}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

def cts(val):
    if val == 'gain':
        return 'color: green'
    elif val == 'loss':
        return 'color: red'
    else:
        return ''

styled_df = df.style.applymap(cts, subset=['Bull - Long Position'])

styled_df

which gives

